# c# Gridview Submit button not able to fire backend generated javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Gridview that come with a button , whenever I done the operation of the button, it should return user a message like success or fail.

My Gridview button as below

```
<asp:Button ID="AddButton" runat="server" Text="Add" CommandName="Add" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" ></asp:Button>
```

If my Back end for handling the button is :

```
protected void gv_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{            
    if (e.CommandName == "Add")
    {
     //Some Function
     //After success display message    
     System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=\"\"JavaScript\"\">alert(\"Hello this is an Alert\")</SCRIPT>"); // Not Showing
    }
}
```

I have try this code `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=\"\"JavaScript\"\">alert(\"Hello this is an Alert\")</SCRIPT>");` in normal post back it is working , but once I put this code into a gridview on command , ,it is not showing and no error.

I try to debug it also can go through without any error , please advice

Comment: ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "Javascript", "<script>alert('Hello this is an Alert')</script>"); try this out rather using System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write();

Comment: @KrunalPatil Same thing not showing

Comment: does your button post back to your gv_RowCommand() ?

Comment: your code is working perfectly well, and popping an alert.. the issue may be somewhere else..

Comment: @KrunalPatil my function is able to complete within gv_RowCommand , even I debug the clientScript code it can go through as well. but it just did not pop up at the GUI.

Comment: now try this. it is working : ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "<script type='text/javascript'> $(function() { alert('Hello this is an Button Alert'); }); </script>");

Answer (score 1):

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('Success.');", true);

Answer (score 0):

Replace your

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=\"\"JavaScript\"\">alert(\"Hello this is an Alert\")</SCRIPT>");
```

with ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()

**Solution 1 :**

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "<script type='text/javascript'> $(function() { alert('Hello this is an Button Alert'); }); </script>");
```

Also remember to give reference of some js script to your head tag  in designer page when you try to run ClientScript. Unless your page is inheriting some Master Page which contains other js references.

Reference Example :

```
   // if you dont give reference the about code will throw an exception : $ is not defined
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Solution 2 :** (Don't need to add reference just remove "$(function() { });" from the Solution 1)

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Hello this is an Button Alert'); </script>");
```

it will surely give you Alert.
Happy Coding..!!

Comment: why need to give reference ?

Comment: did you try using the code without any reference? check my edited answer in the Example section.

Comment: do let me know if that answered your question.

Comment: i have try to both code , the code it self does not have any problem, it work on post back , but once I put it into rowCommand , the code is fired , but just not popping out

Comment: Hi krunal , ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('Success.');", true); this is working some how. Thanks for your answer as well

Comment: Great. at least your issue is solved. Please select the answer so that it is helpful for future viewers.